# Java reverse line than words than letters of the word

Tags: java

am trying to do the following to a txt file, 1- reverse the line so that the last line is the first and so forth, 2- reverse the words to that the last word in a line is the first, 3- reverse the letter of the words.

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws FileNotFoundException {
        ArrayList<String> revStr = new ArrayList<String>();

        Scanner input = new Scanner(new File("mobydick-1.txt"));
        while (input.hasNextLine()){
            revStr.add(input.nextLine());
        }
        for(int i = (revStr.size()-1); i >=0 ; i--){
            String ar[]=revStr.get(i).split(" ");
            for(int j = (ar.length-1); j >=0; j--){
                stringReverse(ar[j]);
                System.out.print(ar[j]+ " ");   
                }
            System.out.println(" ");
            }
    }
   private static String  stringReverse(String string) {
       if (string == null || string.length() == 0) {
           return string;
      }
       return stringReverse(string.substring(1)) + string.charAt(0);
   }
```

any suggestions? so far i was only able to do the first 2 and am stumbled on the 3rd which is reversing the letters of the word
input

```
MOBY DICK; OR THE WHALE 

by Herman Melville


CHAPTER 1

Loomings.
```

output

```
.sgnimooL

1 RETPAHC


ellivleM namreH yb

ELAHW EHT RO ;KCID YBOM
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to continue using your algorithm, Better to use `StringBuilder` then for reversing string you can use `StringBuilder.reverse()` or make a simple function like below one to do any reversal for you.

```
String stringReverse(String string) {
    if (string == null || string.length() == 0) {
        return string;
    }
    return stringReverse(string.substring(1)) + string.charAt(0);
 }
```

Comment: well i've tried implementing a reverse method in my loops but it still didnt reverse the letters it didnt change the outcome at all, am trying to implement it before i print the word itself

Answer (score 0):

What you need to do is read the file in reverse, i.e., from the last character in the file.

Try using [ReversedFileReader from apache.commons](http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-io/apidocs/org/apache/commons/io/input/ReversedLinesFileReader.html#readLine%28%29). Or if you don't like to use external API, you can use [RandomAccessFile](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/RandomAccessFile.html) from JDK.

Answer (score 0):

The error is at

```
 for(int j = (ar.length-1); j >=0; j--){
      stringReverse(ar[j]);
      System.out.print(ar[j]+ " ");   
 }
```

It must be as

```
 for(int j = (ar.length-1); j >=0; j--){
         ar[j]= stringReverse(ar[j]);
         System.out.print(ar[j]+ " ");   
 }
```

Comment: ohh thanks a lot works fine now, any reason why you have to at the ar[j] ? why do we have to use ar[ j] twice?

Comment: You should assign the return value of method to a variable. I used same ar[j] here .. you can use any other string variable and print the same